# Injecting a Bar with an already existing Foo

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guava, guice

Consider the existence of a `Foo` some time in the app. Now `Bar` objects depend on a `Foo`. I want to create this bar based on this `foo` I already have, but Guice creates a new instance of `Foo` every time. I can have a lot of `Foo`s, so I cannot `@Singleton` Foo.

I tried to use scopes for this purpose, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I know this can be solved with `@AssistedInject` but I do not want to take this solution because these associations are common in my context and the dependency is only one. Also, since I am working on creating a tool based on Guice, all I got is a `Foo`, and `Bar.class` and I want to create instances of `Bar` with the given Foo. I am not aware if there are any factories or so.

```
public class InjectionTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Module module = new AbstractModule() {
            ReceiverScope receiverScope = new ReceiverScope();

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindScope(ReceiverScoped.class, receiverScope);
                bind(Foo.class);
            }

            @Provides
            @Singleton
            public ReceiverScope scope() {
                return receiverScope;
            }
        };

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
        Foo foo = injector.getInstance(Foo.class); //assume a given foo

        ReceiverScope scope = injector.getInstance(ReceiverScope.class);
        scope.enter();
        scope.seed(Key.get(Foo.class, Existing.class), foo);
        Bar bar = injector.getInstance(Bar.class);//Create a Bar with this foo
        scope.exit();

    }

    private static class Foo {
        @Inject
        public Foo() {
            System.out.println("foo created" + toString());
        }
    }

    @ReceiverScoped
    private static class Bar {
        @Inject
        public Bar(@Existing Foo foo) {
            System.out.println("bar created with foo" + foo.toString());
        }
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @BindingAnnotation
    private static @interface Existing {
    }
}
```

`ReceiverScope` is a class identical to [Simple Scope given here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomScopes).

Another way I can think of is if I manually iterate `Bar`'s contructor parameters and for each parameter, I ask guice to give me an instance, but if it is a `Foo`, I give my value. But won't this give me a very hard time? I mean I will have to consider a lot of things, because in the constructor might be extra Qualifiers on parameters and stuff...

**EDIT (after @kendavidson's answer):**

This is true. I thought it makes my question more complicated, that's why I did not include it. `Bar` is an interface. Fields in `Foo` contain an annotation which has a `Class<? extends Bar> barClass()` method. For example:

```
@ContainsBars
private static class Foo {
    @MakeBar(BlueBar.class)
    private Something aSomething;
    
    @MakeBar(BlackBar.class)
    private SomethingElse aSomethingElse;
    
    
    @Inject
    public Foo() {
        //create aSomething
        //create aSomethingElse
    }
}
```

Now, whenever Guice injects a `@ContainsBars`, I listen it via a `TypeListener` and I go to create the bars. I scan `Foo.class` and I get `BlueBar.class` & `BlackBar.class`.

The problem I am trying to solve is, how to create `BlueBar` when `BlueBar` has a dependency to `Foo.class`? Whenever this happens, I need to create the `BlueBar` with the Foo I was taken from the listener.

Reflecting constructor was one of my thoughts however it sounds a pain in the ... I guess, it will need to iterate each parameter of the `@Inject` constructor of `BlueBar.class`. If the parameter is of type `Foo`, I give my Foo. If it is a different type, ask the injector to give me an instance of that type. The thing is, how do I do this. When Guice injects, it takes in consideration possible binding annotations (Qualifiers) and generics. Doing that again, sounds pain.

In the other hand, these `@ContainsBars` annotated classes by 99% chance have no relation to each other.

Adding a method to `Bar` interface like `setFoo(Foo f)` will not work. It will have to be a generic. Therefore, method injection with a setter will be cast unsafe. As far as I am aware of, and assuming `BlackBar implements Bar<Foo>`, when I will `Bar b = injector.getInstance(BlackBar.class)`, It will give me a `Bar<?>`. That means, I can't call the setter safely.

Field injection is interesting. Having something like this:

```
public class BlackBar implements Bar {
        private MyDepedency dep;
        
        @Existing
        private Foo foo;

        public BlackBar(Foo foo,MyDepedency dep) {
            this.foo = foo;
            this.dep = dep;
        }
    }
```

seems ok. Whenever, I get a `BlackBar`, I go find the `@Existing` field, and then set the value. I do not care for the value in constructor. Let's say:

```
    Foo foo = ...
    Bar bar = injector.getInstance(BlackBar.class);
    setExistingFieldWithValueOf(foo,bar);
```

The problem here is that whenever I ask injector, it sees the `Foo` dependency, and it is creating a `new Foo` in order to inject. Then, I go change its value. This will cause an infinite loop since during `Foo` injection which is a `@ContainsBar`, the process will be repeated. Even if i manage to stop the infinite loop, still the creation of a new Foo that will never be used seems a bad overhead. If there is a way to inject with `null` value to `foo` in the constructor, let me know. I will use this.

Comment: So, how often do you want different `Foo`s? One for every `Bar`? One for all the `Bar`s?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire One for every bar. But the `Foo`s are already created. Then I want for each Foo, to create a bar with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now, how do you create your `Bar`? Is it `Foo` that creates it?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire No. Foo only knows types. Fields in `Foo.class` contain annotations. Each annotation declares a class e.g `Bar.class`, `OtherBar.class`. Then, given a `Foo`, I go and create an instance of `Bar` and an instance of `OtherBar`. These classes might or might not depend on a `Foo`, but its the most common phenomena. If they depend on a `Foo`, I want to give the instance of `Foo` I was given.

Comment: Then, I'm sorry to say you that scoping is the wrong tool for the job. You'll only get further until you can't, and you'll have lost a significant amount of time, because scoping is rather hard to do, and to do right. But you've already dismissed the right tool for the job, which is `@AssistedInject`, because it does exactly what you want at the cost of creating a new interface for each type of bar you have, switching the code to using that interface, and adding a line in the module.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I was expecting this about the usage of scope. However, the problem I have with `@AssistedInject` is that the amount of the depended classes (`Bar.class` in example) are many. So for each one of them I will need a factory. Also, they will all have the same structure. Only one dependency to a particular class (`Foo.class` in my example). Is there a way to create dynamically, "under the good", (during binding phase) a dynamic factory for each `Bar.class` and then use it? Should I open a new question about it?

Comment: No, you don't need one factory *class* for each `Bar`. You can have a `interface SomeFactory { Bar bar(Foo foo); Baz baz(Foo foo); Quux quux(Foo foo); }`, and if you use classes instead of interfaces, you don't even have to write the `.implement(Bar.class, Bar.class)` in the module declaration. That's the lightest you can do, as far as I know it. I haven't dug deeper in assisted inject because I don't mind grouping assisted-injection in one interface, but I doubt there exist any way to generify this process.

Comment: Ok, next couple things (1) What do you do with the Bars once you created them?  Your example is just creating them using the Injector (this is easy) but unlikely your end goal of where they will be made available?  It doesn't look like they are inside `Foo` so where? (2) Does `BlueBar` ALWAYS have the same `Foo` type? (I seriously hate foo/bar) I would assume yes `class BlueBar extends Bar<T extends AllowedFoo>` {} (3) If you don't annotate `Foo` with `@Inject` it will not be seen and will not be injected, so you will not get the circular dependency that you're worried about.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a shot in the dark and if I'm missing something please let me know.  First off, I definitely think AssistedInject is a solid choice, with a minimal footprint for each `Bar`.

A couple things missing from your question and comments are:

- What are some sample annotated fields of Foo?
- How do you expect multiple Bars to be created?
- Are you dealing with `Bar` and `OtherBar` implementations? Or are you dealing with `Bar` and `<T extends Bar>` interface?

Based on some of these things, it might be doable with:

```java
// BarProvider.java
public class BarProvider {
  // Get the injector, frowned upon but required
  @Inject Injector injector;

  public <T extends Bar> T get(Foo foo, String fieldname) {
    // Provider right now returns on Bar at a time, I'm guessing this is based on
    // fieldname, which can lookup the @Annotation to get the class
    Annotation annotation = ...;

    Bar bar = ...;
    // Now you need to create the bar, this can be done in a couple of ways:
    // Option 1 is to reflect the Bar(Foo) constructor 
    // then doing an injector.injectMembers(bar) to fill the remaining fields

    // Option 2 is to use field/method injection and doing a combination of 
    // Bar bar = injector.getInstance(annotatedClass); followed by
    // bar.setFoo(foo);

    return bar;
  }
}

// Foo.java
public class Foo {

}

// Bar.java
public interface Bar {

}

// ABar.java
public class ABar {
  
}

// BBar.java
public class BBar {

}
```

In both cases you would not `@Inject` the `Foo` field in `Bar`.  Again this makes some assumptions on how you know which field you want to look at in Foo for the annotation class type.

Another option would be to return all of them using:

```java
public <T extends Bar> T[] get(Foo foo) {
    // Same thing but loop through all Annotated fields
}
```

In both cases I'm assuming that `Bar` and `OtherBar` are actually implementations of the same interface which means you'd always be using `Bar` as a return type.  It's still possible otherwise, just a little more annoying.

Hopefully I'm not way off base, and something might be helpful.  But again `AssistedInject` the way it was described above would still probably be a better solution.

**Edit 1 - Circular Dependencies**

If you have these classes, for example, you will not have issues with Foo being injected and then overwritten.

```java
public abstract class Bar<T> {
   T foo;

   setFoo(T foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
   }
}

public class BlackBar extends Bar<Foo> {
   @Inject Dep1 dep1;   // Injected
   @Inject Dep2 dep2;   // Injected
   
   BlackBar() {}
}

@ContainsBar
public class Foo {
    @BlackBar
    SomeObject someObject;
}
```

Now in your example:

```java
Foo foo = injector.getInstance(Foo.class);   // Inject SomeObject
Bar bar = injector.getInstance(BlackBar.class);  // Inject Dep1 and Dep2
bar.setFoo(foo); // Set Foo manually
```

This won't cause the problem you think it does, because `Foo foo` is NOT annotated with `@Inject` therefore Guice won't create a new one when building `BlackBar`.

But this still doesn't answer how exactly you're USING your bars.  I also have a feeling I'm missing something very important to the end goal.

Comment: Thank you for your time & effort. I updated my question. If any further clarifications needed, let me know.